# error in compilation; recursion in function;

Tags: function, c++11, recursion, probability

This code I wrote is supposed to find probability. However I keep getting compilation error that I am unable to understand and recognize. Help would be very much appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
float probability (float w,float b)
{
    float p;
    if(w+b > 1)
    p = ((w*b*2)/(w+b+1)(w+b))*probability(w-1, b) + (2*b*(b-1)/(w+b+1)(w+b))*probability(w, b-2) + (2*w*(w-1)/(w+b+1)(w+b))*probability(w-1, b);
    else if (w == 1 && b == 0)
    p = 0;
    else
    p = 1;
    return p;
}


int main()
{
    float white, black;

    cin>>white>>black;
    float P = probability(white, black);
    cout<<"The probability that Nishant wins is: "<<P<<endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: please post the error as well in the code

Comment: What is `(w+b+1)(w+b)` supposed to do? If you mean multiplication, then you have to say so: `(w+b+1) * (w+b)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thankyou very much. I completely forgot about that. I can't imagine being so careless. Please pardon my beginner's nuisance.